# EditText setError showing icon but no text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an EditText set up like this:

```
        <EditText android:id="@+id/etField1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none" android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"/>
```

`Focusable` is set to false, because I want that the user just clicks on the EditText and a dialog will be displayed.

I set the error as follows:

```
etField1.setError("some error text");
etField1.requestFocus();
```

However, because `focusable` is false, only the icon is displayed. The error text is not shown.

Setting `focusable` to true will show the error text but this is not an acceptable workaround.

Are there any other solutions to display the error text?

Comment: you could use spannable to achieve that

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono you want to display the error message after click on edittext?

Comment: @User I want to display error text when using setError()

Comment: you want focusable=false also with setError display the error message?

Comment: as usual you just set focusable=false in xml file.if you click on EditText just enable the focusable=true,now i think your problem resolved.just follow my answer.

Answer (score 3):

just try like this:

**Xml:-**

```
   <EditText android:id="@+id/edit"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:longClickable="false"
              android:cursorVisible="false"
              android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
              style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"/>
```

put this code in your activity class.

```
   EditText text3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
        text3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                text3.setFocusable(true);
                text3.setError("some error text");
                text3.requestFocus();
            }
        });
```